# Set a window's background color in Ruby curses

Tags: ruby, curses

Trying to add a background to a curses window. I have these two properties

I've found these two methods:

```
bkgd(ch)
```

and

```
bkgdset(ch)
```

However, I can't implement them:

```
win1.new(10,10,10,10)
win1.box('|','-')
win1.bkg(COLOR_RED)
```

This fills win1 with a load of diamonds! Very insteresting effect but not what I wanted. I want a red background.

Colors work perfectly in my terminal.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to set background colors in ruby's curses lib? I can get background characters to show but it seemingly ignores my colors.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while, but maybe my examples are still useful:

It is the same "diamonds" for me when using

```
window.bkgd(COLOR_RED)
```

This seems to appear, because the `bkgd` method takes a *char* and prints it to all free spaces of the window (see [old doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/curses/rdoc/Curses.html#method-c-bkgd)).

However, then you can use a color pair with the wanted background color and apply it to all screen positions before writing oher stuff.

Here is how I solved it:

```
require 'curses'    

init_screen
start_color

init_pair(COLOR_RED, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_RED)
window = Curses::Window.new(0, 0, 0, 0)

window.attron(color_pair(COLOR_RED)) do
  lines.times do |line|
    window.setpos(line, 0)
    window << ' ' * cols
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is to use the `color_pair` method inside of the `bkgd` to use the particular color combination. For your example, it should be:

```rb
window.bkgd(color_pair(COLOR_RED))
```