# How can I easily set the curses window background color in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, curses

The ruby code below prints two windows (overlapping) via `Curses`. The first "border" window prints in black/cyan and the "content" window prints in blue on cyan.

The content window only displays the background color where text is printed. The rest of the content window remains black. The ruby dox describe ways to manipulate window backgrounds using either `color_set`, `bkgd` or `bkgdset` methods. I can only get `color_set()` to work however and only for text that is being printed:

[image]

How can I fill the reset of the content window with the appropriate background color? I found some code to [Set a window's background color in Ruby curses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19438195/set-a-windows-background-color-in-ruby-curses) but it does not seem to work and is quite old.  The only other idea I have is to right-pad the string with spaces to fill the entire window with the background character but this seems reeealy hacky.

EDIT: added code

EDIT2: added "hacky padding" work around

```
    #!/usr/bin/ruby

    require 'curses'

    Curses.init_screen
    Curses.start_color
    Curses.noecho
    Curses.cbreak


    Curses.refresh  # Refresh the screen

    xulc = 10
    yulc = 10
    width = 30
    height = 8

    # text color for border window
    Curses.init_pair(1, Curses::COLOR_BLACK, Curses::COLOR_CYAN)
    Curses.attrset(Curses.color_pair(1) | Curses::A_BOLD)

    # Text color for content window
    Curses.init_pair(2, Curses::COLOR_BLUE, Curses::COLOR_CYAN)
    Curses.attrset(Curses.color_pair(2) | Curses::A_NORMAL)

    # border window   
    win1 = Curses::Window.new(height, width, yulc, xulc)
    win1.color_set(1)
    win1.box("|", "-")

    # content window
    win2 = Curses::Window.new(height - 2, width - 2, yulc + 1, xulc + 1)
    win2.color_set(2)
    win2.setpos(0, 0)

    # only prints in background color where there is text!
    # add hacky padding to fill background then go back and print message
    bg_padding = " " * ((width - 2) * (height - 2));
    win2.addstr(bg_padding);
    win2.setpos(0, 0)
    win2.addstr("blah")

    # prints without the color_set() attributes
    #win2.bkgd ('.'.ord)

    # make content visisble
    win1.refresh
    win2.refresh

    # hit a key to exit curses 
    Curses.getch 
    Curses.close_screen
```

Comment: What code do you have that generates this particular window? It helps to add that sort of thing to the question if it's small enough to make sense as other people can iterate on it and fix your problem.

Comment: oops, pulled it out for an edit and forgot to put it back.

Comment: Which curses library (platform, etc) is being used?  In a quick check, ncurses works as expected.  For other implementations, that may not be the case.

Comment: I don't know what curses implementation the Ruby gem uses. I ran `gem install curses` on Ubuntu 14.04. `gem list` shows `curses (1.2.3)`

Comment: `win.bkgdset(Curses::color_pair(1)` should draw a colored background as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I'll use the hacky padding workaround. Seems to be all I've found so far

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28100035/3536548), the actual code is here:

> It's been a while, but maybe my examples are still useful:
>
> It is the same "diamonds" for me when using
>
> window.bkgd(COLOR_RED) This seems to appear, because the bkgd method
>   takes a char and prints it to all free spaces of the window (see old
>   doc).
>
> However, then you can use a color pair with the wanted background
>   color and apply it to all screen positions before writing oher stuff.
>
> Here is how I solved it:

```
require 'curses'    

init_screen
start_color

init_pair(COLOR_RED, COLOR_WHITE, COLOR_RED)
window = Curses::Window.new(0, 0, 0, 0)

window.attron(color_pair(COLOR_RED)) do
  lines.times do |line|
    window.setpos(line, 0)
    window << ' ' * cols
  end
end
```

Also found [this](http://blog.brandon-conway.com/blog/2013/12/31/using-ruby-curses/):

```
# color_set(col)
# Sets the current color of the given window to the foreground/background
# combination described by the Fixnum col.
main_window.color_set(1)
```

tutorial.html#colors-initialization

Comment: Thanks! That post is actually linked in my question however. Appreciate the effort.